# ASP Code Highlighting in Aptana

Tags: asp.net, syntax-highlighting, aptana

I've been using Aptana 3 for awhile, mostly for HTML, CSS and PHP editing. I just started working a lot with ASP, and right now Aptana isn't syntax highlighting asp files. How do I set it up to do that? Do I have to install a plugin? Add an ASP editor? Flip a switch? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josiah, since Aptana is built upon the Eclipse IDE, I've read that you should be able to use the [Eclipse Colorer Plugin](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/) to achieve syntax highlighting for ASP files - I've never done this myself though. If you started working with ASP, at least in case of ASP.NET I'd highly recommend using Visual Studio (for example the free [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express)) for debugging support and many other features...

Comment: I'm going to be avoiding VS like the plague. I've used it before, and it's so clunky compared to Aptana. Just a personal preference I guess. :)

Comment: Awesome. The Eclipse Colorer Plugin works. There's a nice dark theme included by default as well! Thanks.

Comment: @Josiah Nice to know I could help :) I think it's not about how Visual Studio "feels", it has so many very essential features for ASP development beyond the source code editing (debugging, deployment, dataset editors, entity framework modeller, just to name a few) but if you can live without that? :)

Comment: I've been using the colorer for about 2 months. It's better than nothing, but the lack of functional matching pairs and code suggest make it less than ideal. I guess I'm going to have to settle for Visual Studio. If anyone comes across a better ASP plugin for Eclipse, please comment!

Comment: @Josiah thanks for your Feedback! If you want some lightweight tool for ASP development, you might look at Microsoft *WebMatrix* ( http://www.asp.net/webmatrix ) it's very simple to use and it's power might be underrated :)

Comment: I'm having trouble installing the Eclipse Colorer Plugin. From another post I navigated to File -> Import -> General -> Preferences, but it's wanting an .epf format, but I can't find that in the files... maybe installing it the wrong way? I'm on a Mac too.